# Force loading of all properties in memory when executing NSFetchRequest?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a core data object **RootObject**.
This object has an array/relationship of other objects, **ChildrenObject[]**.

When executing *NSFetchRequest* to get all my **RootObject**s I get an array with all of them.

The way *CoreData* works is that it only loads properties on demand, meaning only when I access my **ChildrenObject** property that property would load from the file.

Something like:

```
RootObject.childrenObjects.firstObject.someChildrenObjectProperty
```

*CoreData* will load *someChildrenObjectProperty* in memory only on first access of that property.

Is there a way to force *CoreData* to load it earlier, somewhere during the *NSFetchRequest* execution?

One option is to iterate through all of the fetched **RootObject** items and just access the properties but I am wondering is there some better way to do this on a *CoreData* level (some setup flag, fetch flag).

Comment: Just curious, why would you like to do that? I cannot think of a reasonable use case.

Comment: RootObject is a photo displayed in UICollectionView. It has an array of ChildrenObjects. I need to iterate through that array to calculate something so I could know how to display my cell based on that. When I launch the app, and fast scroll that collection view I notice a small hiccup. On next scroll everything is ok. I profiled the app and noticed that on that first scroll, some amount of time is spent in ChildrenObject. someChildrenObjectProperty so I figured that is the first time property access and CoreData is reading it from the file.

Comment: Since I would end up anyhow in all that data in memory after first scroll, I wanted to prefetch it from the beginning to avoid this first scroll hiccup. I can optimize this to make sure to only prefetch ChildrenObject array (setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching) which I did. Other option would be to calculate this value on every OtherObject array change but I wanted a quicker solution and this worked out fine for me.

Comment: OK, understood. Thanks for the info. Too bad this won't scale. But I am glad it works.

Comment: Do you have some suggestions? Since those are really lightweight objects so I am thinking it won't make much of memory impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `NSFetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults` and `NSFetchRequest.setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching`